# Não consigo acessar o ip do laravel homestead

Tags: laravel, homestead

Bom dia, estou tentando instalar o Homestead do laravel 5.5, seguindo a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead). No entanto, quando tento acessar o IP 192.168.10.10, que é o ip padrão do homestead, ele fica carregando e não consegue resolver. Isso antes mesmo de se pensar em DNS, apenas o ip, ele já não consegue resolver, com isso o DNS no arquivo /etc/hosts também não.
Já fiz e refiz a instalações umas 3x, mas nada deu certo, pesquisei e pesquisei, recomendaram instalar o gnome-nettools para ver os adaptadores de rede, e vi que tem um adaptador do virtual box que está pegando 192.168.10.1, não sei se isso pode estar errado. Mas queria ajuda pra resolver esse problema, vou deixar abaixo os arquivos /etc/hosts (que no momento não é o problema, assim que resolver o ip, creio que vá ser solucionado o DNS)

Homestead.yaml:

```
    ---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: screencast.app
      to: /home/vagrant/code/screencast

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   matheus-PC

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

192.168.10.10 screencast.app
```

Foto do adaptador de rede vboxnet0
[image: vboxnet0]

Há também o adaptador de rede vboxnet1
[image: vboxnet1]

PS: Estou usando o deepin linux 15.4.1.

PS2: O ip que meu servidor (trabalho) me da é 172.16.10.X, trabalhando assim com a máscara 255.255.255.0.

PS3: Quando jogo o ip 127.0.0.1:8000 ele consegue bater lá, mas creio que isso é pelo redirecionamento criado pelo vagrant (porta 8000 host => 80 guest).

Desde já, agradeço toda a ajuda, obrigado!